# Permutation between three sets in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

I have 3 sets

```
A = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
B = {'1', '2'}
C = {'d', 'e', 'f'}
```

Now what I want is as follows in python:

```
{'a1d', 'b1e', 'c1f'}
{'a1e', 'b1f', 'c1d'}
.
.
.
{'a2e', 'b2f', 'c2d'}
```

all such possible combinations without disturbing set A.

Repetition of elements from set C is not allowed.

eg. `{'a2e', 'b2e', 'c2d'}` is not allowed.

Comment: Please don't use edits to my answer to ask questions; that's what comments are for.

Comment: I am really sorry for that.
Couple of inputs though:
1. I don't want to disturb the order of elements of A.
2. I want to allow repetitions for set B.

Comment: You can produce permutations across `B` with one digit repeated with `permutations(list(B) * 2, r=3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially looping over set `B`, zipping the permutations of `C` with `A`:

```
from itertools import permutations

for b in B:
    for cperm in permutations(C):
        res = {''.join([a, b, c]) for a, c in zip(A, cperm)}
        print res
```

Output:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> A = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
>>> B = {'1', '2'}
>>> C = {'d', 'e', 'f'}
>>> for b in B:
...     for cperm in permutations(C):
...         res = {''.join([a, b, c]) for a, c in zip(A, cperm)}
...         print res
... 
set(['a1e', 'b1f', 'c1d'])
set(['a1e', 'b1d', 'c1f'])
set(['b1f', 'a1d', 'c1e'])
set(['a1d', 'b1e', 'c1f'])
set(['b1d', 'a1f', 'c1e'])
set(['b1e', 'a1f', 'c1d'])
set(['b2f', 'a2e', 'c2d'])
set(['b2d', 'c2f', 'a2e'])
set(['b2f', 'a2d', 'c2e'])
set(['c2f', 'b2e', 'a2d'])
set(['b2d', 'a2f', 'c2e'])
set(['b2e', 'c2d', 'a2f'])
```

where sets are unordered, so the per-set order differs from your output example.

Adding some sorting:

```
>>> for b in B:
...     for cperm in permutations(C):
...         res = {''.join([a, b, c]) for a, c in zip(A, cperm)}
...         print '{{{0!r}, {1!r}, {2!r}}}'.format(*sorted(res))
... 
{'a1e', 'b1f', 'c1d'}
{'a1e', 'b1d', 'c1f'}
{'a1d', 'b1f', 'c1e'}
{'a1d', 'b1e', 'c1f'}
{'a1f', 'b1d', 'c1e'}
{'a1f', 'b1e', 'c1d'}
{'a2e', 'b2f', 'c2d'}
{'a2e', 'b2d', 'c2f'}
{'a2d', 'b2f', 'c2e'}
{'a2d', 'b2e', 'c2f'}
{'a2f', 'b2d', 'c2e'}
{'a2f', 'b2e', 'c2d'}
```

Producing permutations across `B` with one digit repeated can be achieved by doubling the `B` set into 2 lists and picking just 3 elements per permutation:

```
for bperm in permutations(list(B) * 2, r=3):
    for cperm in permutations(C):
        res = {''.join([a, b, c]) for a, b, c in zip(A, bperm, cperm)}
```